# How can you detect when the user clicks on the notification icon in Windows Mobile (.NET CF 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Surfing the net, I came across this:

[this code](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.compactframework/msg/d202f6a36c5c4295?dmode=source&hl=en) that shows how to display a notification at the bottom of the screen on a Windows Mobile device. My question is, is there a way to either specify which options are displayed beneath the notification (on the taskbar) or is there a way to detect when the user clicks on the notification itself, so that I can react to that programmatic ally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this specific API, the key is in the SHNOTIFICATIONDATA's hwndSink member.  When the notification is clicked, the hwnd you pass in here will get the click message.  For this it's simplest to pass in a [MessageWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow(VS.80).aspx)'s handle.

You might also look at the [CeSetUserNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908104.aspx) API instead.  It's actually quite a bit more robust in what it allows you to do and how you can get notifications back at the app.

Comment: You da man! I've noticed that you're the expert around here on CF. Thanks for the info.